# Why Observer Delete in Laravel Not Working

Tags: laravel, observers

I am using Observer for Deleting. In my project, I have two tables: contract_assets and action_logs. When I add the new row in contract_assets (contract_id, asset_id) and use Observer for Created to save log in action_logs table. It's working! But I delete this row and use Observer for Deleting, it's not working.

This is Contract Assets model:

```
final class ContractAsset extends SnipeModel
{
    protected $presenter = 'App\Presenters\ContractAssetsPresenter';
    protected $table = 'contract_assets';

    protected $rules = [
        'contract_id' => 'required',
        'asset_id' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required',
    ];
    use ValidatingTrait;
    use Searchable;
    use Loggable, Presentable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = ['contract_id', 'asset_id', 'user_id', 'deleted_at'];
}
```

This is ContractAssets Controller:

```
 public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('delete', ContractAsset::class);
        $results = ContractAsset::select('contract_assets.id')
            ->where('contract_id', '=', $request->contract_id)
            ->where('asset_id', '=', $request->asset_id);
        $results->delete();

        $listAssets = ContractAsset::select([
            'contract_assets.id',
            'assets.id',
            'assets.image',
            'assets.name',
            'assets.asset_tag'
        ])
            ->join('assets', 'assets.id', '=', 'contract_assets.asset_id')
            ->join('models', 'models.id', '=', 'assets.model_id')
            ->where("contract_assets.contract_id", '=', $request->contract_id)
            ->get();
        return response()->json($listAssets);
    }
```

And this is ContractAsset Observer:

```
public function deleting(ContractAsset $contractAssets)
    {
        $logAction = new Actionlog();
        $logAction->item_type = ContractAsset::class;
        $logAction->item_id = $contractAssets->id;
        $logAction->created_at =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $logAction->user_id = Auth::id();
        $logAction->logaction('delete');
    }
```

This is ActionLog model:

```
class Actionlog extends SnipeModel
{
    protected $presenter = "App\Presenters\ActionlogPresenter";
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Presentable;
    protected $dates = [ 'deleted_at' ];

    protected $table      = 'action_logs';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable   = [ 'created_at', 'item_type','user_id','item_id','action_type','note','target_id', 'target_type' ];

    use Searchable;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be included when searching the model.
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $searchableAttributes = ['action_type', 'note', 'log_meta'];

    public function logaction($actiontype)
    {
        $this->action_type = $actiontype;
        if ($this->save()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I delete row in contract_assets table, deleted_at column updated:

id | contract_id | asset_id | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at

140|  42         | 11       | 2019-08-20 02:07:35 |  2019-08-20 02:07:38 | 2019-08-20 02:07:38

But action_logs not updated this row deleted.
I have used `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:cache` it not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what your logaction() function does but to you need to do $logAction->save() to save the model to the database.

Comment: I have updated the action log model and logaction() function above